# How to selectively output some specific index with it's value from an array with for-loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

> The program should check that if there's heights that are more than 180 cm in the array, then it should print the index and the value of the height using for-loop. (e.g. Student 4: 185 cm)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Kursteilnehmer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner p = new Scanner(System.in);
        int students;
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of students: ");
        students = p.nextInt();

        // The number of students should be entered

        double[] height = new double[students];
        System.out.println("Please enter the height of every student: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
            height[i] = p.nextDouble();

            //The height of every student muss be entered
        }

        // how to output the students that are taller than 180 cm with for-loop??

        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < students; i++) {
            sum = sum + height[i];
        }
        System.out.println("The sum of every height is: " + sum + " cm");
        System.out.println();
        double average = sum / height.length;
        System.out.println("Average height: " + average + " cm");

        //The average height will be given
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this a the point where you want to get the output. You are going through every entry in the array. With `height[i]` you get the element at the current index. If the current height is over 180, it will print the statment.

```
System.out.println("Students taller than 180 cm");
        for (int i = 0; i < height.length; i++) {
            if (height[i] > 180) {
                System.out.println("Student " + i + ": " + height[i]);
            }
        }
```